# want paths but stuck on vectors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, path, cs2

I have adobe Photoshop cs2 and I would like to use paths(I use the line tool and shapes to do so) and I have before however I don't know if I clicked something but now when ever I try to use the box tool it either fills in the shape or makes it into a vector all I want is it to make its out line.Also with the line tool it isn't just a simple line like it was before either its now like a thin rectangle rather then a line like I want it to be. If anyone knows how to fix this please let me know I need all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have selected "Shape layer" rather than "Paths", here how to solve it.

First select shape tool or pen tool and select Paths as shown in image.

[image]